# Order of TestNG listeners (java Webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium, listener, testng

I have two listeners, both extending ITestListener. One takes screenshots on fail/pass, and the other uploads the fail/pass results to a service.

One of the items that gets uploaded is the location of the screenshot that was taken. However, sometimes the upload listener uploads before the screenshot is taken, so there's no filepath to upload.

Is there a way I can set the order of the listeners? I know I could solve this by making one listener that performs both tasks, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Why not combine then. My listener both creates the snapshot and uploads it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, because different listeners should not depend on each other.

We are using TestNG with Selenium too.

There is only one `ITestListener`, which stores the exception message into an attribute of `ITestResult` (in case of an error).

All our test cases are extending one base class, which defines it's own `@AfterMethod` - here we are analyze `ITestResult`, and reporting the result afterwards.

In your case, you could leave the screenshot functionality in your listener, but if you move the report functionality in the base class, you can guarantee that it's called after `onTestFailure` (or other methods of `ITestListener`)